# How is censorship on the radio constitutional?

Tags: united-states, constitution

I listen to the radio from time to time and it really gets me thinking about how the censorship laws work.

With the Constitution granting freedom of speech I don't really understand how radio and TV stations can block out certain words. I also don't understand how it's possible for radio stations to broadcast certain words (such as "bitch") but after the song has been out for a while no station seems to play it with this word.

In the end does banning radio stations from using certain vocabulary break the Constitutional law?

Comment: and actually some people actually do  believe that censoring the airwaves is against the constution

Comment: I suppose this question should be clarified. There is no codified censorship of Radio Airwaves. There are 'decency' laws that the FCC can enforce, however, but they are usually addressed on a case-by-case basis rather than via sweeping regulation.

Comment: "With the Constitution granting freedom of speech" I think that the Founding Fathers might wince at this, and argue that freedom of speech is a natural right and that the Constitution doesn't *grant* freedom of speech, but rather *guarantee* it by preventing Congress from passing a law that inhibits it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The airwaves are public property, so the broadcasters have to adhere to the rules set by the owners of the airwaves (ie, the public...ie, the government). The FCC has set particular guidelines, though they have been fuzzy at times.

The FCC doesn't directly censor, but can enact penalties for the fuzzy concept of 'indecency', so one could argue that, indirectly, they can influence what is or isn't said.

Comment: So FCC is a federal organization?

Comment: So since FCC enforces fines on usage of certain words and it is a federal organization technically it does mean that its making laws about freedom of speech. So it would be unconstitutional. "Congress shall make no law respecting an establishment of religion, or prohibiting the free exercise thereof; or abridging the freedom of speech"

Comment: @Xitcod13 The 'F' in FCC stands for 'Federal'. As for your follow-up question Affable's answer addresses that. Freedom of speech does *not* mean you can say anything anywhere at any time.

Comment: @DA Well that would be complete freedom of speech but i agree that no country has complete freedom of speech.

Answer (score 6):

The first amendment does not confer unlimited rights to speech, but rather guarantees "free expression." In [Schenck v. US](http://caselaw.lp.findlaw.com/scripts/getcase.pl?court=US&vol=249&invol=47), (1919h, Oliver Wendell Holmes most famously gave the hypothetical of "[shouting fire in a crowded theater](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shouting_fire_in_a_crowded_theater)"). The right to cause panic is not the same as the right to freely express a political opinion. When there is an overwhelming state interest in protecting a portion of the population, speech can be regulated.

Common decency amongst large portions of the population suffices as a similar compelling state interest - there is a legal right to shield your children from obscenity. As Potter Stewart famously wrote of pornography in [Jacobellis v. United States](http://caselaw.lp.findlaw.com/scripts/getcase.pl?court=us&vol=378&invol=184), [I know it when I see it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_know_it_when_I_see_it). Regardless of whether or not one thinks this *is* an abridgment of free speech, there is legal precedent and reasoning for it.

Indeed, the overall rationale for the FCC requiring "[seven dirty words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_dirty_words)" to be bleeped out (and for say, certain wardrobe malfunctions to be blurred) is that parents have as much right to shield their child's from obscenity as the producer of it has to make it available.

In short, free expression means you can say what you want, but it doesn't require that I have to listen to it.

Comment: I have links to Schenck v. uS and Jacbellis, but for some reason the markdown isn't taking...

Comment: The 7 dirty words aren't codified in any specific way as being restricted on the radio.

Comment: You don't have to listen to it. You choose to listen to the radio.

Comment: "Oliver Wendell Holmes most famously gave the hypothetical of "shouting fire in a crowded theater")."  And from that same Wikipedia link "Justice Holmes began to doubt his decision due to criticism received from free-speech activists ... Holmes's change of heart influenced his decision to join the minority and dissent in the Abrams v. United States case"

Comment: @Xitcod13 You choose to listen to a given radio station (or none at all) but, unlike books where there can be infinite variety, there can only be a finite number of radio stations due to bandwidth restrictions (this is less true/untrue in the world of internet radio). Because it's a limited (and public) resource, the FCC have been put in chargew of licencing its use. Think of it like them leasing out federal land (and attaching conditions to the lease).